# How to write variable values on text file or Excel file in Cypress.io?

Tags: javascript, excel, selenium-webdriver, cypress

Does anyone know how I can write the variable values on Text or Excel sheet? 
I have variable `tex` and it stores the string values and i want to write those values on textfiles or Excel sheet( preferable)

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/closest.html#Syntax')
  })
it('go to the home page', () => {
  cy.get('.sidebar-link').each(($el, index, $list) => {
    const tex = $el.text()
  cy.writeFile('/Users⁩/⁨Desktop⁩/2.txt', tex) // <= This piece of code is printing only last stored value
  })
});
```

I know there is `cy.writeFile` but not sure how i can use it.

Comment: it will take only string array or object as parameter are you sure about that. and what error you are getting post that.

Comment: Hi @vikas I was able to print only last stored values to file 2.txt files. so when I open this file I can see "After Screenshot" is stored( or we can written) in a text file.

**"After Screenshot"** is last store text, there are more than 100 elements associated with this **".sidebar-link"** locator so I can grab the text value and want to write on text file

Comment: You must use `cy.readFile()` and then merge the new text with the old one. `cy.writeFile` will override the whole content

Comment: @JosefBiehler do you have any example?  how I can use `cy.readFile()` ?

Comment: @Gurinder I can not test the code right now but it should be something like this:     cy.readFile("/some/path/to/file.json").then(txt => {
        cy.writeFile("/some/path/to/file.json", txt + "something new from the current test run")
    }) It is the same handling as `cy.writeFile`

Answer (score 0):

working code:-

```
const texts = [];
cy.get('.sidebar-link').each(($el, index, $list) => {
    texts.push($el.text());
}).then(() => {
    cy.writeFile('/Users/Desktop/1.txt', texts.join("\n"));
```